# Encrypting a stream received via Formidable.js before streaming to S3

Tags: aws-sdk-nodejs, formidable, node-streams

I have a file parsing function in Express.js which is taking multiple files coming in via Formidable and streaming them to S3, without storing them on the server:

```
const parseFile = async (req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const s3Uploads = [];
        const fileWriteStreamHandler = async (file) => {
            const body = new PassThrough();
            const upload = new Upload({
                client, params: {
                    Key: `files/${Date.now().toString()}-${file.originalFilename}`,
                    ContentType: file.mimetype,
                    Bucket: s3Config.bucket,
                    Body: body,
                    Region: s3Config.region
                },
                queueSize: 4,
                partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
                leavePartsOnError: false
            });
            const uploadRequest = upload.done()
                .then((response) => {
                    file.location = response.Location;
                })
                .catch(
                    function(error){
                        console.log(error.message)
                        reject(error)
                    }
                )
            ;
            s3Uploads.push(uploadRequest);
            return body;
        }
    const form = formidable({
        multiples: true,
        fileWriteStreamHandler: fileWriteStreamHandler,
    });

    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
            return;
        }
        Promise.all(s3Uploads)
            .then(() => {
                resolve({ ...fields, ...files });
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error.message)
                reject(error)
            }
            );
    });

    });
}
```

I would like to encrypt the stream, so that the file gets to AWS already encrypted.

This seems like a decent library for the job: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-encrypt-stream

The sample code:

```
setPassword(Buffer.from('f8647d5417039b42c88a75897109049378cdfce528a7e015656bd23cd18fb78a', 'hex'));
const stream = new PassThrough();
await createEncryptStream(body).pipe(stream);
```

The issue is that I'm having a hard time understanding where to hook this functionality into the flow. Is it in the fileWriteStreamHandler function? How can I access the stream Formidable is getting from the request in order to pipe it into the body PassThrough stream? Or is it something I need to pass as a callback to form.on for a certain event?

This:

```
setPassword(Buffer.from('f8647d5417039b42c88a75897109049378cdfce528a7e015656bd23cd18fb78a', 'hex'));
const stream = new PassThrough();
createEncryptStream(stream).pipe(body);
return body;
```

results in a

> TypeError: this._writeStream.on is not a function

error being thrown here from Formidable's https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/blob/master/src/VolatileFile.js.